# angular-material input with an addon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, material-design, angular-material

I'm trying to create an input with an extra text after it using [angular-material](https://material.angularjs.org/). I want to achieve a similar effect as with [bootstrap's .input-group-addon](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups):
[image]

The closest I got is [this](http://codepen.io/LukaszWiktor/pen/gpXXxW):

```
<md-content layout-padding>
    <div layout="row" class="md-whiteframe-z1" style="width: 40%">
        <md-select placeholder="Type" ng-model="discount.type" flex="50" class="md-select-full-width">
            <md-option value="AMOUNT">Amount</md-option>
            <md-option value="PERCENT">Percent</md-option>
        </md-select>
        <div flex="50" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
            <md-input-container flex>
                <label>Value</label>
                <input ng-model="discount.value">
            </md-input-container>
            <span>%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-content>
```

What gives following result:
[image]

As you can see the 2 fields are misaligned.

I also tried to use `vertical-align` on the `<span>%</span>` instead of `layout-align="center center"` but it seems to be ignored.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle with your code? sorry for offtopic, aside from the subject, seems that you're trying to combine 2 different design libraries - material and bootstrap and this problem you have may be not the only.. maybe could be usefull, another library implementing material design approach - http://materializecss.com/forms.html

Comment: @shershen I created a codepen entry: http://codepen.io/LukaszWiktor/pen/gpXXxW

Comment: @shershen I'm using only material and I've mentioned boostrap just as an example to show what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out a solution using `<md-icon>`:

```
<md-content layout-padding>
    <div layout="row" class="md-whiteframe-z1" style="width: 40%">
        <md-select placeholder="Type" ng-model="discount.type" flex="50" class="md-select-full-width">
            <md-option value="AMOUNT">Amount</md-option>
            <md-option value="PERCENT">Percent</md-option>
        </md-select>
        <div flex="50" layout="row">
            <md-input-container flex>
                <label>Value</label>
                <input ng-model="discount.value">
            </md-input-container>
            <md-icon md-font-set="regular-font">%</md-icon>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-content>
```

The `"regular-font"` is some non-existing icon font library to make sure that the text inside `<md-icon>` won't be interpreted as an Material icon.

Now it's well aligned:

[image]

You can see the working solution here: http://codepen.io/LukaszWiktor/pen/oXoqYg

Answer (score 3):

I just figured out a way to do this too for when you'd like the add-on to contain something more than a single character, using flexbox.

```
<md-input-container flex>
    <label>Length</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="length" flex="80">
    <span flex>seconds</span>
</md-input-container>
```

The important parts are `flex="80"` on the `input` element, and `flex` on the `span`. This is telling the `input` to take up 80% of the space, and for the `span` to fill the remainder (at least I think so - I'm still learning flexbox).

The end result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I made it look a little more alike bootstrap style this way:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
     <label for="discount">Discount</label>
     <input style="text-align: right; padding-right: 15px;" type="text" id="discount" ng-model="discount" ng-change="updateDiscount()">
     <span style="margin-top: 5px; position: absolute; right: 0;">%</span>
</md-input-container>
```

Screenshot for your review:

[image]